# Missing Expression in oracle struggling

Tags: sql, oracle, expression

```
CREATE TABLE OT_PAY (
    PAB_ITEM_ID                CHAR(5 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
    HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER         NUMBER(4,2)                NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT                   OT_PAY_PK          PRIMARY KEY(PAB_ITEM_ID),
  CONSTRAINT                     OT_PAY_FK1      
    FOREIGN KEY(PAB_ITEM_ID)
    REFERENCES OT_PAY(PAB_ITEM_ID),
  CONSTRAINT HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER CHECK (HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <='1.00' and >='3.50')
    );


Error starting at line : 77 in command -
CREATE TABLE OT_PAY (
    PAB_ITEM_ID                CHAR(5 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
    HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER         NUMBER(4,2)                NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT                   OT_PAY_PK          PRIMARY KEY(PAB_ITEM_ID),
  CONSTRAINT                     OT_PAY_FK1      
    FOREIGN KEY(PAB_ITEM_ID)
    REFERENCES OT_PAY(PAB_ITEM_ID),
  CONSTRAINT HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER CHECK (HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <='1.00' and >='3.50')
    )
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: so you don't have 77 lines in this text, try running it as a standalone script and show us the errors.  In your previous question we suggested to not use CHAR as it is best practice to use VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2

Comment: Could you please take the time to formulate a question instead of just posting error messages? Where is the error from? In which context did you get that? What have you tried to find or fix the error?

Comment: What is the point of a foreign key constraint that just refers to itself? You did that in an earlier question but it wasn't clear if that was a mistake or you were expecting it to achieve something. There's less of an obvious meaning this time.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, there are several issues with that check.

**1-** You shouldnt compare number with strings so

```
  HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <='1.00' and >='3.50'
```

Should be:

```
  HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <=1.00 and  >=3.50
```

**2-** Sintaxis error, you cant write conditional that way, you need:

```
  HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <=1.00 and HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER >=3.50
```

**3 -** The range doesnt make sense because `HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER` cant be less than 1 and greater then 3.50 at the same time so yo need invert the `<=` or use `OR`

```
  HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER >=1.00 and  HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <=3.50
```

Finally you can use `between` instead

```
  HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER BETWEEN 1.00 and 3.50
```

Comment: Ah, but the BETWEEN option doesn't do the same thing that OP had written (although it's probably what was meant). :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis Yes, I was just reading your answer. I was focus on only a part of the problem. You deserve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <='1.00' and >='3.50'` => `HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <='1.00' and HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER >='3.50'`

Use number literals instead of strings - `HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER <= 1 and HOLIDAY_MULTIPLIER >=3.5`